# Windows 10 Activation With Windows 7 Key

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-activation, product-key

Is it possible to activate a copy of windows 10 with a windows 7 key after July 29th? I missed the time frame and want Windows 10.

Comment: I attempted to but the upgrade failed

Comment: See this...http://betanews.com/2016/08/03/microsoft-to-close-free-windows-10-loophole/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you previously upgraded and successfully activated Windows 10 on that machine, you missed out on the free upgrade.

You'll have to [purchase it](https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Windows-10-Pro/productID.319935900) now.

Comment: I attempted to but the upgrade failed

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't matter.  You should have dealt with that problem before the deadline hit.

Comment: I've seen a few people mentioning that it still in fact works, even though it shouldn't. This article from zdnet would appear to confirm this - http://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-free-upgrade-is-still-available-using-windows-7-and-8-product-keys/?ftag=TRE17cfd61&bhid=22322828174359121101636554590268

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I finally successfully repaired my Win7 x64 computer few days ago and gave it a try this way:

1. I downloaded [Windows10 x64 unilang ISO from microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)

   - *Note: it was still the 1607 release*
   - *Note: I did not use Windows for this download but a Linux rescue OS to avoid being redirected to the upgrade webpage*
2. Burnt it on a DVD (did not boot for me using an USB flash drive)
3. Installed it

   - *Note: I used the fresh install option (I didn't care my very old files on disk)*
   - *Note: I skipped the key registration on this step*
4. Once Win10 installed, I activated it from the control panel using my Win7 key.

In fact, I <strike>think</strike> hope such option will remains in the future for anyone being able to re-install a crashed win10-upgraded computer using their win7 activation key.